# Thymeleaf and replacing with html entity

Tags: thymeleaf, html-entities

Having an issue replace a hyphen (-) with a non breaking hyphen in thymeleaf.

```
<p th:utext="${#strings.replace('1-800-123-4567456745674567456745674567','-','&#8209;')}" ></p>
```

I've tried to use a `\` before the `&` to to escape it but that doesn't work either. I want my final output to be: `1&#8209;800&#8209;123&#8209;4567456745674567456745674567`. Any ideas? Thank you.

Edit: To clarify; thymeleaf will do the actual entity encoding and enter the final product, i don't want the final product. I just want the entity code to be there as shown above.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand your question properly, but let me provide with different options and you pick the answer you need ...

1. The replacement has actually happened and the string printed in the browser is unbreakable.
2. Instead of using Thymeleaf you may just want to use the `style="white-space: nowrap;"` in your `<p>` tag to get the unbreakable string.
3. Finally the weird request to get the escaped string printed in the browser page you may do something like this ... (this produce the string you would like to see)

   ```
    <p th:utext="${#strings.escapeXml(#strings.replace('1-800-123-4567456745674567456745674567','-','&amp;#8209;'))}" ></p>
   ```

EDIT: After your edit, I believe the answer to your question is #3.